# How to enable hot swap with google app engine, maven and eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, hotswap

Following the instruction of Google at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven
somehow changes in jsp files are not picked up, while changes in java files are.

So when I change a java file, I get the following log:

> [INFO] INFO: A file has changed, reloading the web application.

But when I change a jsp or html file, it is not picked up and the old content is shown in the browser.

My pom.xml file includes the lines:

```
<build>
<outputDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory> 
...        
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <fullScanSeconds>1</fullScanSeconds>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
```

After some research I see some suggest to use a filesync type of solution, but it seems a bit odd. 
Shouldn't it work out of the box with the maven and gae plugin in eclipse? 
Without maven it works fine, but without maven, you'll have to deal with the jar dependencies yourself.
Without hot swap / hot code replacement, the maven solution in eclipse with gae is not a good development environment.

Answer (score 2):

> But when I change a jsp or html file, it is not picked up and the old content is shown in the browser.

Just execute "mvn package" at the "myapp" directory(not myapp-ear or myapp-war) when i change the java code or jsp code. so it works(hot deploy).
hope that would be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [m2e-wtp](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP) plugin, which acts as a bridge between m2e and wtp projects. Whether this solves your problem may depend on which version of eclipse you're using.

Comment: I should have added that the m2e (1.4.0) and m2e-wtp (1.0.1) plugins where already installed. The Eclipse version I use is Kepler.

Comment: And the hot swapping behaviour you're looking for is using the eclipse 'run as google webapp', rather than command line?

Comment: Ideally I would use 'run as google webapp', but with maven I do 'run as > maven build > appengine:devserver'.
I think the issue has to do with maven scanning the target folder, but the target folder is only populated if you do a maven package. That however slows the dev process.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app engine app on your local development server with the help of goal "appengine:run", it keeps on watching the changes in files and whenever you make some change and save them, plugin automatically deploy it on already running development server.

There is no need of any extra configuration.

You can simply test this as follows;

1. Implement a GET endpoint(testApi/v1/getName) returning "String" and return any name like "Aashish".
2. Execute the goal "appengine:run" and this will run your app on local development server.
3. If you hit this GET - http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/testApi/v1/getName in browser, you will see "Aashish".
4. Now, go to eclipse, just change this returning text to "Ajay" and save and hit same GET api in browser and you will see "Ajay"